# Multiple Pages controlled by 1 controller with the views in multiple locations - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Not 100% sure this is possible but was requested by a colleague to make his life easier.

We have an archive of our newsletters that are sent out and the site is in a CodeIgniter framework with a couple of controllers for the different newsletters. The controller is set up as follows:

```
<?php

class Software1 extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($software1 = 'home') {

        if (!file_exists('../application/views/software1/' . $software1)) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
        $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/links.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/footer.php');

        $data['title'] = basename($software1, ".html");

        $this->load->view('templates/common/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('software1/' . $software1, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/common/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

So this means that currently the views are pulled from the software1 folder. The email views are labelled December 2013.html, January 2014.html etc. This works fine but my colleague asked if it was at all possible if he could separate put all of 2013 e-mails in a 2013 folder and 2014 in a 2014 folder so it makes his life easier to sort out.

Is it possible to have the controller look in multiple folders for the views or is there any other way I can achieve this so that all of the 2013 would be in software1/2013/Month 2013.html and that 2014 would be in software1/2014/Month 2014.html

Yes I know I could create separate controllers per year but am trying to avoid this and if there is a good way to do this using so if and else then that would be great. If it is not possible then that's fine I will just tell him to upload to one folder and leave it like that but any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

EDIT//

Current Folder Structure:

```
application/
---controllers/
------archive.php
------software1.php
---views/
------Software1/
---------Archive.html
---------January 2013.html
---------Febuary 2013.html
---------March 2013.html
---------April 2013.html
---------May 2013.html
---------June 2013.html
---------July 2013.html
---------August 2013.html
---------September 2013.html
---------October 2013.html
---------November 2013.html
---------December 2013.html
---------January 2014.html
```

And oviously have to take into account future years as well ie 2015,16,17 etc.

The I need to be able to easily define the urls in the route file currently the outes look like:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Software1/$1/$2/$3/$4';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Software1/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Software1/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'Software1/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'Software1/index/home.html';
$route['Archive'] = "ArchiveSoftware1/index/Archive.html";
$route['2013/January'] = "Software1/index/January 2013.html";
$route['2013/March'] = "Software1/index/March 2013.html";
$route['2013/May'] = "Software1/index/May 2013.html";
$route['2013/July'] = "Software1/index/July 2013.html";
$route['2013/September'] = "Software1/index/September 2013.html";
$route['2013/November'] = "Software1/index/November 2013.html";
$route['2014/January'] = "Software1/index/January 2014.html";
```

As it appears my question is about as clear as mud lol hopefully this will help:

So I want the folder structure:

```
application/
---controllers/
------archive.php
------software1.php
---views/
------Software1/
---------Archive.html
------------2013/
---------------January 2013.html
---------------Febuary 2013.html
---------------March 2013.html
---------------April 2013.html
---------------May 2013.html
---------------June 2013.html
---------------July 2013.html
---------------August 2013.html
---------------September 2013.html
---------------October 2013.html
---------------November 2013.html
---------------December 2013.html
------------2014/
---------------January 2014.html
```

Each 1 of those views is an individual webpage online the only common things they have is they are sharing the header and footer files. What I am trying to do it have 1 controller that goes if goes to url.net/2014/January will display the info in the January 2014.html view file (as I have said I have this working if the subfolders 2013 and 2014 are not there ie everything in the software1 folder and I can have this working if I use multiple controllers ie 1 for 2013 and 1 for 2014 etc. however I am trying to have it so I can do this in 1 controller that so it will look at any of the subfolders to find the correct file to display as defined by the route file.

As I said I have no idea if this is actually do able but hopefully someone can understand what I am trying to acheive and give me some way of doing this :)

Comment: yes you can  For eg: $this->load->view('modules/maint/booking/booking');

Comment: Yes but that is loading from just 1 folder I need it to look at multiple folders as all 2013 would be in one folder and all 2014 would be in another somehting like software1/' . $year, $software1, $data but need to probably write something to help choose the $year that is what I am not sure to do or if it is possible. Should point out that the urls are as follows: software1.websiteurl.net/Year/Month

Comment: do you want to create view folders using code?

Comment: The site is up and running I dont need to create folders with code. The e-mail files that are in pure html (as the guy who deals with them does not know any code relating to the web he just adds text to a template I created for him) are uploaded into the software1 folder he would like to put into multiple folders inside the software1 folder depending upon the year ie he uploads to software1/2014 for all of the 2014 newsletters. I thought of maybe havig it so it uses the last 4 digits (which is the year) excluding the file extension from the file names of the views not sure if this is possible

Comment: yes you can .In software1 folder you can create any number of folders like 2013,2014 etc. What stuff you want to insert in that folders?

Comment: add your folder structure to the question

Comment: Ok I not sure I am being very clear I know I can create these folders and upload but I need to know how I can tell the controller which folder to pull the newsletter from as the route file defines the url as follows: $route['2013/December'] = "software/index/December 2013.html";

Comment: Ok have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

In my view page One folder is modules.
That contains different folders.
One of that is fault.And that again contains booking,add,deleted folders.
And each of these contains different php files.

We can write:

```
$this->load->view('modules/fault/booking/booking');
$this->load->view('modules/fault/booking/schedule');
$this->load->view('modules/fault/booking/delete');

$this->load->view('modules/fault/add/file');
$this->load->view('modules/fault/add/add');
$this->load->view('modules/fault/add/edit');
$this->load->view('modules/fault/add/delete');
```

etc...

Comment: Ok not 100% sure what you mean can you show me the code I would need to add to make all this possible I should point out there is no db involved on this site (would make my life so much easier if there was but that is a different story :) )

Comment: But that is just loading multiple views into one page. Each Newsletter needs its own page

Comment: Just realsied the origional question was a bit unclear have altered